# vectorize, reshape, and normalise my image to image like mnist.train.images

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

How can I vectorize, reshape, and normalise my image to the same as the size vector of one of the images in `mnist.train.images`? I've tried the below so far with no success:

```py
import os
import re
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import os,sys
#import Image
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets

# Load data and check the shape of the first mnist.train.images image 
data_dir = 'temp'
mnist = read_data_sets(data_dir)
print("tmnist.train.images[0].shape is")
print(mnist.train.images[0].shape) # the result is (784,)

def resize_image(image):
    img = Image.open(image)
    arr = np.array(img)
    #my mind is drawing a blank... additional code to make this work...
    return arr


resize_image("test.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
def resize_image(image):
   img = Image.open(image)
   img = img.resize((28, 28))
   arr = np.array(img)

   #convert to gray scale
   if len(arr.shape) > 2:
     arr = np.mean(arr, 2)

   #flatten 
   arr = arr.flatten()
   return arr
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. For the normalisation, I added: from sklearn import preprocessing;
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler();
arr_train_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(arr); Seems to be working. Hope it's consistent with mnist.train.images's normalization